# Adjuntar y enviar un .ZIP con 2 archivos por medio de Python

Tags: python, gmail

Me muestra el siguiente error:

> **adjunto.set_payload(open(adjunto,'rb').read())
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not MIMEBase**

Codigo:

```
remitente='remitente@gmail.com'
destinatario='destinatario@gmail.com'
asunto='Archivos Comprimidos'
cuerpo='Archivos comprimidos y enviados desde Python'
adjunto='C:\\Users\\SOFTRONIK\\Desktop\\HUJMB\\CompresorArchivos\\archivosPrueba\\archivos.zip'
nombreAdjunto='archivos.zip'

mensaje=MIMEMultipart()
mensaje['From']=remitente
mensaje['To']=destinatario
mensaje['Subject']=asunto
mensaje.attach(MIMEText(cuerpo,'plain'))
adjunto=MIMEBase('application','octect-stream')
adjunto.set_payload(open(adjunto,'rb').read())
adjunto.add_header('content-Disposition',"attachment; filename=%s" % nombreAdjunto)
mensaje.attach(adjunto)
sesion_smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
sesion_smtp.starttls()
sesion_smtp.login('remitente@gmail.com','******')
texto=mensaje.as_string
sesion_smtp.sendmail(remitente,destinatario,texto)
sesion_smtp.quit()
print('Correo enviado exitosamente')
```

Comment: El problema está en esta linea: `adjunto=MIMEBase('application','octect-stream')`. Allí estás reemplazando el valor de la variable adjunto (que era el directorio del zip) por una instancia de MimeBase. La solución: cambia el nombre de la variable para evitar dicho reemplazo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expandiendo en el comentario de Dante, este es el código final una vez aplicado el cambio sugerido:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
import smtplib

remitente='remitente@gmail.com'
destinatario='destinatario@gmail.com'
asunto='Archivos Comprimidos'
cuerpo='Archivos comprimidos y enviados desde Python'
adjuntozip='archivo.zip'
nombreAdjunto='archivos.zip'

mensaje=MIMEMultipart()
mensaje['From']=remitente
mensaje['To']=destinatario
mensaje['Subject']=asunto
mensaje.attach(MIMEText(cuerpo,'plain'))
adjunto=MIMEBase('application','octect-stream')
adjunto.set_payload(open(adjuntozip,'rb').read())
adjunto.add_header('content-Disposition',"attachment; filename=%s" % nombreAdjunto)
mensaje.attach(adjunto)
sesion_smtp=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
sesion_smtp.starttls()
sesion_smtp.login('remitente@gmail.com','******')
texto=mensaje.as_string
sesion_smtp.sendmail(remitente,destinatario,texto)
sesion_smtp.quit()
print('Correo enviado exitosamente')
```

Comment: Excelente... Muchas gracias... Solamente era cambiar la ruta del archivo adjuntar que esta errada...!!! Muchas Gracias